# Question stil shows up under "tagged questions" after tag is removed

Tags: bug, tags

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28544577/repeat-while-loop-according-to-the-user-input) just was shown to me among the "tagged questions" for C++. When I looked at it, the tag had just been removed and the only remaining tag was C. Going back to the "tagged questions" for C++, it still showed up, with only the C tag. Reloading the page or changing tag filters to C# and back to C++ did not help, the question was still there.

It took several minutes until it eventually disappeared from the C++ tagged questions.

Answer (score 8):

This is a case of http://shouldiblamecaching.com/.

Wait a while, those pages are *heavily* cached, this is by design and not a bug. Stack Exchange cannot hope to serve [560 million page views per month](https://stackexchange.com/performance) without caching things aggressively.